# Do broadcast reciever relies on binder or intent, Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver, android-binder

When I set up a  `broadcast reciever` in Android. Does this, on the lowest levels rely on `Binder`? or can you get around `Binder` in any way?

Answer (score 2):

> Does this, on the lowest levels rely on Binder?

I do not know what you consider "the lowest levels" to be. Certainly, sending a broadcast using `sendBroadcast()` and kin will use `Binder`, to pass the request to a core OS process for execution.